# How do you call data from nested JSON array using d3?

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js

I have nested arrays in my json data, but I don't know how to call them in the d3 (beginner).

In the example below, I am trying to build an SVG bar chart, using data from the "January" array, nested in the "meals" array in Json.

The Json looks like this:

```
{
"meals":[
    {"january":[
        {},{}
    ]},

    {"february":[
        {},{}
    ]},

    {"march":[
        {},{}
    ]},
  }
```

And the d3 code looks like this. "chart" takes the user input of a drop down menu. In this case, it basically returns "meals":

```
    var chart = selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].id;

    var dataset = data[chart];

    var svg = d3.select ("body") 
                .append ("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", svgHeight+30);


    svg.selectAll("rect") 
                .data(dataset.january) //***HERE is where I'm having trouble***
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
```

Comment: Is the json object already loaded? Or is it in a separate file?

Comment: Yes, it's in a separate file and already loaded.

Comment: .data(dataset) should work then; if not you probably should post a jsfiddle. Any number of things could be going wrong.

Comment: The value of `data.meals` is an array. Hence you would have to access it with `dataset[0], dataset[1], ...`. However, since each of the objects only contains one property, you might wan to use an object instead of an array of objects.

Comment: hhmmm...that doesn't seem to work. The page loads, but no rect is created. I need arrays, because I am trying to create a double bar chart and will be adding additional data.

Answer (score 1):

`d3.nest()` can convert data like that into parseable arrays. These 'tutorial' examples are great: http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/

Given that it's feasible with your project, it might otherwise be better to simply change your data formatting for an easier traversal e.g.

```
{
"meals":[
    {"name":"salad","month":"january"},
    {"name":"burger","month":"february"}, //etc...
```